# Quarterly breakdown by month

Tags: oracle

I'm working in oracle db.
I have a table `rent`
[image]

Me need to create a procedure that will display the column count by month and quarter. Need result like:
month_1 - x
month_2 - y
month_3 - z
quarter - q

I'm create this procedure

```
    create or replace procedure p_money
    (c_id in out rent.car_id %TYPE,
    RS in out rent.rent_start %TYPE,
    RE in out rent.rent_start %TYPE,
     v_result IN out sys_refcursor)
    as
    begin
      open v_result for
      select sum (money) "TOTAL"
      from rent 
      where c_id = rent.car_id and rent_start between RS and RE and rent_end between RS and RE
     group by rollup (money);

    end p_money;
```

Comment: There is no question; what is it that you need help with? Do you get an error? Is the output not what you're expecting? Please edit your post to add more details, including the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this simple query will give you some idea

```
with 
    sample_data as (
        select sysdate + dbms_random.value(1,500) dt,
               round(dbms_random.value(100,300),2) money
          from dual
       connect by level < 1000 
    ),
    enriched_data as (
        select  dt,
                trunc(dt,'q') q,
                trunc(dt,'mm') m,
                money
          from  sample_data
    )
select q,m, count(*), sum(money) 
  from enriched_data
 group by rollup (q,m);
```

- `sample_data` is just some random sample data in a form of `(dt, money)`
- in the `enriched_data` we calculate month and quarter for each `dt`
- finally, we group this data using `group by rollup (q,m)` and receive the subtotals